# Can't upgrade past 11.10 - libc6 dependency errors

Tags: 11.10, apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

Since upgrading to 11.10 I can't upgrade any further (trying to get my web server to latest version.) I'm aware of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) and have tried up to the point of running this:

```
apt-get remove --dry-run libc6
```

..but the output is scary and I'm worried about removing this package or at least until I understand what I'm doing better.

Here is the output of apt-get upgrade:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.15) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is installed
libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5.3) but 2.15-0ubuntu20.2 is installed
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu20.2) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is installed
libnih-dbus1 : Depends: libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu11) but 1.0.3-4ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Obviously I've done what it says to no avail.

Can anyone suggest a safe way to fix these issues? Ultimately I'm trying to get my web server to the latest version of Ubuntu so maybe there's a way to bypass this. Note that I have command line access only. I've got a few live websites there that are easily backed up but otherwise nothing too critical.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Rob

Answer (score 2):

11.10 is [no longer supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) since 9 May 2013. Upgrading all the way to 14.04 is a long call.

I suggest you backup your data and install 14.04 from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. So out of interest if I'd have upgraded to a new release each time they came out rather than trying to upgrade through each release one at a time now, what would have been the difference?

Comment: Upgrading from one release to the next is pretty easy. As a side note, for a server you may want to consider limiting yourself to Long Term Support releases for greater stability and less frequent upgrades (every 2 years instead of 6 months). You're in luck, because 14.04 is an LTS release.

Comment: Ok thanks. So any idea how I might solve my original issue so I can upgrade through each version?